# Movie where aliens or cyborgs were searching for the hero who is locked in a police cell

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am in search of a movie (or maybe series) that I had once on VHS until it was overwritten.

Aliens/cyborgs looked somewhat similar to Chaos Space Marines.

I remember the scene where the main actor and his girl were locked at local town PD/sheriff's and these alien/cyborgs were searching him. After they managed to escape from cells by using some acid ampules, bad guys attacked and the good guy dispatched one with an SMG of some sort by repeatedly firing rounds at enemies' hearts/cores.

I think that good guy's name was Ballard.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When was this?  Obviously not recently if it was a VHS :) but that still leaves potentially a couple of decades range.

Comment: Well, if Ballard were the woman, it might be [*Ghosts of Mars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_of_Mars), but I don't know how good a match it is otherwise.

Comment: When I watched this, it was in '90s... and yes Ghost of Mars is all I get when I try to befriend Google...

edit:
in this movie there was a domed city, there was a superweapon in some energy stream. Entire setting was war-like, with time/dimension travel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be *[The Time Guardian](https://chud.com/101745/collecting-vhs-the-time-guardian-1989/)*?

> In the 24th century, the last civilization on Earth faces extinction at the hands of a race of evil cyborgs. A futuristic warrior is sent back to our present in an attempt to save the damaged city, which is spinning out of control in both time and space.

It does have a scene where they escape jail while under attack.

### Trailer

Found with a search for `film cyborgs "named ballard"`

Comment: Carrie Fisher why?

Comment: Thank you! it is the one I was looking for!

Comment: Geez, but that movie was terrible!